# Write a file with Prototype or plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, prototype

I know the question has been asked thousands of times, but I'll ask it again: is there a way (even patchy) to write/read a dumb text file with Javascript or Protoype ?

This is only for debug purposes, and is not designed for production. The thing is I need it to work with (at least) both Firefox and IE (preferably under Windows).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Clarify the meaning of 'with'. Do you mean 'using' or 'which executes'?

Comment: I mean, is there a way that a Javascript or Prototype script can write a plain text file ?

Answer (score 3):

Writing to a file is not possible, you'd have to write a server-side script and make a request to that script. Reading is possible if you use an iframe with the text file's location as source, and reading the iframe contents.

Answer (score 2):

**It *is* possible to read/write to a local file via JavaScript**: take a look at [TiddlyWIki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/). *(Caveat: only works for local documents.)*

I have actually written a [Single Page Application](http://softwareas.com/towards-a-single-page-application-framework) (SPA) using [twFile](http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html), a part of the TiddlyWiki codebase:

1. Works in different browsers: (IE, Firefox, Chrome)
2. This code is a little old now. TiddlyWiki abandoned the jQuery plugin design a while ago. (Look at the [current TiddlyWiki filesystem.js](http://dev.tiddlywiki.org/browser/Trunk/core/js/FileSystem.js) for more a more recent implementation. It's not isolated for you like the twFile plug-in, though).
3. Although written as a jQuery plug-in, I've studied the code and it is almost completely decoupled from jQuery.

**Update:**
I have uploaded a [proof-of-concept](http://coolcases.com/jeopardy/) that accesses a local file via JavaScript.

- Modifying this application to write to a file is trivial.
- <strike>I have not tried to get this to work as a file served from a web server, but it should be possible since there are [server-side implementations of TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.org/wiki/Can_I_use_TiddlyWiki_as_a_multi-user/collaborative/server_based_wiki%3F)<</strike>>.

**Update:**

So it looks like the server side implementations of TiddlyWiki use a server "adapter" to modify a file stored on the server, similar to [Peter's description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195720/write-a-file-with-prototype-or-plain-javascript/3195752#3195752). The pure JavaScript method will probably not work if the page is served from a web server due to cross-domain security limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript in browsers doesn't allow you to write local files, for **security reasons**. This **may change with time**, but as for now you have to **deal with it**.

Answer (score 1):

Only with a server side javascript interpreter, but that isn't the typical environment you run javascript in.

Answer (score 0):

What about cookies? It is accessible via javascript, it is on your client and it is a plain text file. Only issue is the size of it (4k max if I remember well).

What you can do as well is use your browser localStorage / userData / globalStorage (depending on your browser version). It acts like cookies (new webStorage / HTML5 specs) but can handle bigger amounts of data. Then, using some add ons (firebug on firefox for instance) you can easily read / copy / past the value and do whatever you have to do with it!